# Change static folder - express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm making a NodeJS app with express, and I would like to send the user to another page in an `app.post` function.

I know that you can serve pages by using something like this: `app.use(express.static('client/home'));` and this is working in my app, but when I put this into my `app.post` as follows below, the page just says "localhost didn't send any data".

```
app.post('/createSchool', function(req, res) {
  app.use(express.static('client/school'));
});
```

If I add `res.end('');` after `app.use`, then the page doesn't crash but I'm met with a blank screen.

How can I get Express to serve the HTML in the `client/school` folder?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a `res.sendFile` after `app.use`. The function is now as follows:

```
app.post('/createSchool', function(req, res) {
  app.use(express.static('client/school'));
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/client/school/index.html'));
});
```

The reason I didn't add this is because it wasn't needed at the start. Why is this, by the way?

**Edit: ** When I remove the `app.use` in the POST method (leaving me with just `res.sendFile`, the page still works as intended. So why do I need `app.use`? I thought it was to serve all the files in the folder together, i.e. HTML, CSS and JS, as just using res.sendFile just gives you the bare HTML.

I'm really confused now...

Comment: Does the html need extra files (CSS, JS)? If so, they should be at your static folder ( that's the way it works, at least...)

Comment: The HTML does need extra files, and yes, they are in the same folder. I thought just `res.sendFile` only showed bare HTML though.

Comment: Can you access your file through the url? Something like `http://localhost:3000/js/script.js`?